# @click individual object from data array within v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, click, v-for

Very new to Vue and js on that matter really, most likely I have missed a basic fundamental issue but I am trying to toggle the class of individually clicked images within my array without all of the images toggling class at the same time.

template :

```
   <div class="collage-banner">
                <img
                    v-for="image in images"
                    @click="imgSelected()"
                    :alt="image.alt"
                    class="collage"
                    :class="image.class"
                    :src="image.url"
                    :key="image"
                />
```

js :

```
export default {

data() {
    return {
        images: [
            { url: img1, class: "img-1", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img2, class: "img-2", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img3, class: "img-3", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img4, class: "img-4", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img5, class: "img-5", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img6, class: "img-6", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img7, class: "img-7", alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img8, class: "img-8", alt: "collage img" }
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
    imgSelected() {
        if (this.images[0].url === img1) {
            this.images[0].class = 'collage-click'
        } else if (this.images[0].url === img2) {
            this.images[0].class = 'img-1'
        }
        if (this.images[1].url === img2) {
            this.images[1].class = 'collage-click'
        } else if (this.images[1].url === img1) {
            this.images[1].class = 'img-2'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Let me know if further info is needed, I more than likely have gone about this the entirely wrong way! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to set a click handler? Can you confirm you are following this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Comment: Hi, yes I want to set a click handler so if I click on the (for example) second image, only the second image will change it's class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the image index into your `imgSelected` method, and use this to update class for that image.

**For example:**

Template:

```
<img
  v-for="(image, index) in images" << updated
  @click="imgSelected(index)" << updated
  :alt="image.alt"
  class="collage"
  :class="image.class"
  :src="image.url"
  :key="image"
/>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
    imgSelected (index) { // add index param
            // use index to get relevant image from array
            this.images[index].class = 'collage-click'
    }
}
```

If you want to remove class from selected images e.g. user clicks image 1, then image 2, you'd have to also loop through your images and reset the class before updating on latest clicked image.

E.g.

```
methods: {
        imgSelected (index) {
            // reset all image classes
            for (const i in this.images) {
               this.images[i].class = `img${i + 1}` // reset image class e.g. img2 (need to add 1 to index since it will start at 0)
            }
            
            // use index to get relevant image from array
            this.images[index].class = 'collage-click'
        }
    }
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, much appreciated! If I wanted to make the click event a toggle class instead of add class would it be much different? For example: user clicks image 1, then image 1 again to revert to previous class?

Comment: @Dean For that you'd need to change the line setting the class to:
this.images[index].class === 'collage-click' ? `img${index + 1}` ? 'collage-click'

This uses, conditional statement to check if the class is already 'collage-click' and if it is sets it to the imgNUMBER class

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be having a flag called `clicked` in the images array and toggling class based on that Boolean.

```
data() {
    return {
        images: [
            { url: img1, class: "img-1", clicked: false, alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img2, class: "img-2",clicked: false, alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img3, class: "img-3",clicked: false, alt: "collage img" },
            { url: img4, class: "img-4", clicked: false, alt: "collage img" },
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
    imgSelected (index) { // add index param
            // use index to get relevant image from array
            this.images[index].clicked = !this.images[index].clicked;
    }
}
```

and in template

```
<img
  v-for="(image, index) in images" << updated
  @click="imgSelected(index)" << updated
  :alt="image.alt"
  :class="['collage', {`${image.class}`: !image.clicked, 'collage-click': image.clicked}]"
  :src="image.url"
  :key="image"
/>
```

Note: if you want the `collage` to always be applied then you can have it in the array.
If you don't want the collage class at all and jus wanna toggle between  `img1` and `collage-click`, you could jus have an object like

```
:class="{`${image.class}`: !image.clicked, 'collage-click': image.clicked}"
```